# Cassandra cluster on budget

Tags: cassandra

I am learning Cassandra and want to run a cloud based cluster. I don't care much about speed.

What I want to really test is the replication and recovery features.

I would be running tests like

- taking nodes offline every once in a while
- kill -9 cassandra
- powering off server
- manually corrupting sstables/commitlog (not sure if this is recoverable)

I am thinking of going for a 4 node cluster.

Each node will have the following config:

```
2 GB RAM
10 GB SSD
2 CPUs (Virtual)
```

Two nodes will be in a European datacenter and other two will be in a North American data center.

I know 8GB is the recommended minimum for Cassandra. But that config would be quite expensive.

If it helps, I can run one more VM on a dedicated box. This VM can have 16 GB RAM and 8 virtual CPUs. I could also run 4 VMs with 4GB RAM each on this box. But I guess, having 4 separate VMs in different data centers would make a more realistic setup and bring to fore any issues that may arise out of network problems, latencies etc.

Is it okay to run Cassandra on machines with this config? Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Is your question for a test cluster to "kick the tires" or for something you would evaluate and use in production?

Comment: Somewhere in between. I won't be expecting it to scale to billions of rows, or for it to be fast. But I do expect the replication and recovery features to work like they would on a production system.

Answer (score 1):

Many people run multiple instances of cassandra on modern laptops using ccm ( https://github.com/pcmanus/ccm ). If you just want to get an idea of what it does (create a 3 node cluster, add data, add a 4th node, create a snapshot, remove a node, add it back, restore the snapshot, etc), using ccm on a PC may be 'good enough'.

Otherwise, you can certainly run with less than 1GB of ram, but it's not always fun. There have been some clusters on tiny hardware ( http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/32-node-raspberry-pi-cassandra-cluster ). Depending on your budget, making a cluster on raspberry pi's may be as cost effective as your 2 VM cluster.

Comment: I actually have a Pi with me and I was thinking about exactly this yesterday. Was watching a youtube video from 2012 whee the person used a 512 MB Pi. I think it can be done better with 1 GB Pis that are available today but I am afraid it will be turn more into a Raspberry PI experiment than a Cassandra one.